WebStorm "Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json"
I am working on a TypeScript project using node.js and use WebStorm as my IDE. It always worked well until a few weeks ago when the IDE started randomly showing the "Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json" error. It seems to always happen when the IDE uses ESLint and Prettier to reformat my code (for example on save).
I have no idea what my problem could be. I suspect that it's probably an issue with my TypeScript configuration so I'd appreciate if someone even has an idea for what I could check, update or reconfigure to fix this. This is really annoying and makes it impossible to work on this project.
I have tried invalidating caches, using the "Repair IDE" button, reinstalling WebStorm and resetting all my WebStorm settings to default, but it didn't change a thing. The same thing happens when I open the project using GoLand.

I am working with WebStorm 2024.2.1 (just updated today, the same issue also happened on WebStorm 2024.2.0 and 2024.1) on Fedora 40, using node 22.8.0 (previously used node 21.1.0, which worked before but upgrading did not change anything). As a package manager, I use yarn 4.1.1. Node.js is installed using nvm.
This is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    },
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

Additionally, I have this tsconfig.eslint.json:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["../node_modules", "node_modules"]
}

And these are my dependencies from the package.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.5",
    "@types/config": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2",
    "@types/eslint": "^8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.20",
    "@types/google-protobuf": "^3.15.12",
    "@types/luxon": "^3",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
    "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.2",
    "grpc-tools": "^1.12.4",
    "grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts": "^5.3.3",
    "prettier": "3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bufbuild/buf": "^1.29.0",
    "@bufbuild/protobuf": "^1.7.2",
    "@bufbuild/protoc-gen-es": "^1.7.2",
    "@connectrpc/protoc-gen-connect-es": "^1.3.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^2.2.0",
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.10.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "discord.js": "^14.13.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "mysql2": "^3.7.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.3",
    "pino": "^8.17.2",
    "pino-pretty": "^10.3.1",
    "protoc": "^1.1.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.2",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.6",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "yaml": "^2.3.4"
  },

As stated above, I would really appreciate if someone has any idea as to where this issue could come from and how I could fix it. If you need any more additional info or configuration files, let me know. Thanks in advance!

File -> Repair IDE and go next step repair
